# How to create python C++ extension with submodule that can be imported

Tags: python, c++, cpython, python-extensions

I'm creating a C++ extension for python. It creates a module `parent` that contains a sub-module `child`. The `child` has one method `hello()`. It works fine if I call it as

```py
import parent
parent.child.hello()
> 'Hi, World!'
```

If I try to import my function it fails

```py
import parent
from parent.child import hello
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parent.child'; 'parent' is not a package

parent.child
> <module 'child'>
```

here is my code
**setup.py**

```py
from setuptools import Extension, setup
  
# Define the extension module
extension_mod = Extension('parent',
                          sources=['custom.cc'])

# Define the setup parameters
setup(name='parent',
      version='1.0',
      description='A C++ extension module for Python.',
      ext_modules=[extension_mod],
      )
```

and my **custom.cc**

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <string>

std::string hello() {
    return "Hi, World!";
}

static PyObject* hello_world(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
    return PyUnicode_FromString(hello().c_str());
}

static PyMethodDef ParentMethods[] = {
    {nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr}
};

static PyMethodDef ChildMethods[] = {
    {"hello", hello_world, METH_NOARGS, ""},
    {nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr}
};

static PyModuleDef ChildModule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "child",
    "A submodule of the parent module.",
    -1,
    ChildMethods,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr

};

static PyModuleDef ParentModule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "parent",
    "A C++ extension module for Python.",
    -1,
    ParentMethods,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_parent(void) {
    PyObject* parent_module = PyModule_Create(&ParentModule);
    if (!parent_module) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    PyObject* child_module = PyModule_Create(&ChildModule);
    if (!child_module) {
        Py_DECREF(parent_module);
        return nullptr;
    }

    PyModule_AddObject(parent_module, "child", child_module);

    return parent_module;
}
```

I install and build with `python setup.py build install`.

So, how do I make sure that my `parent` is a package?

My code is a toy example but I actually want both modules defined on C++ level. I don't want to split them into several modules - since they are sharing some C++ code.

I'm hoping for something similar to approach of this answer [Python extension with multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65260969/python-extension-with-multiple-modules/65373203#65373203)

Comment: Did you have a chance to take a look at [nanobind](https://github.com/wjakob/nanobind) or friend? They make creating C++ extensions considerably easier.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) or [Boost.Python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/index.html)?

Comment: @mdf yes, I was trying to reorganize some legacy code without drastic changes. pybind11 is definitely nice especially since it's headers only.

Comment: Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but if you wrap your C++ in plain C, you can use ctypes (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) to create a python module that wraps your C wrapper. Using that you can structure the python wrapper to access the underlying code however you want including what you describe above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this from within the extension is a "simple" matter of **emulating** the behavior for modules that the import system recognizes as packages.  (Depending on context, it might be nicer to provide an import hook that did the same thing from the outside.)  Just a few changes are needed:

1. Make the **name** of the child `"parent.child"`.
2. Make `parent` a **package**:

   ```
   PyModule_AddObject(parent_module, "__path__", PyList_New(0));
   PyModule_AddStringConstant(parent_module, "__package__", "parent");
   ```
3. Make `child` a **member** of that package:

   ```
   PyModule_AddStringConstant(child_module, "__package__", "parent");
   ```
4. Update **`sys.modules`** as Python would if it had performed the import:

   ```
   PyDict_SetItemString(PyImport_GetModuleDict(), "parent.child", child_module);
   ```

Of course, several of these calls can fail; note that if `PyModule_AddObject` fails you have to drop the reference to the object being added (which I very much did not do here for clarity).

Comment: I think this is what I’m looking for, can’t test right now, hope it works.

Comment: @BlacKow This is interesting, but really hacky to achieve a simple and common task. I wonder why you are fighting against the Pythonic way of building & publishing your package. If you want to use standard tools like `poetry`, `pip`, `conda` to release your package to PiPy and Anaconda, simply follow the convention of the python community. Is it really so hard to add the `__init__.py` file and set the correct option in your `setup.py` / `setup.cfg` / `pyproject.toml`?

Comment: This method is really useful when, for some reasons, the package (containing sub-modules) must end up as *a single binary file* in the user's site-package folder.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use [`packages`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages) option.

This is the standard way, as many popular C/C++ python packages like
[tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/setup.py#L334),
[pyarrow](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/65520b361941e9abad386614999dbc250295959e/python/setup.py#L476)
[meinheld](https://github.com/mopemope/meinheld/blob/master/setup.py#L98) and
[greenlet](https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet/blob/master/setup.py#L220) are using it.
Also it is recommended by the Python Packaging [Authority](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#custom-discovery).

The only important points are adding the [`packages`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html) keyword option to setup and naming your module as `"parent.child"`:

```py
# Define the extension module
extension_mod = Extension('parent.child', ... )

setup(
  name='parent', 
  packages=["parent"], 
  ext_modules=[extension_mod], ... 
)
```

That's it. No need to hack around. Also note that `ext_modules` is not always required, because you can build the  C/C++ assets of sub modules separately. See the setup scripts of tensorflow and pyarrow for examples.

It is important to add `__init__.py` under the "parent" folder, because , otherwise, it would not be treated as a [package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

> when you say `packages = ['foo']` in your setup script, you are promising that the Distutils will find a file `foo/__init__.py`  relative to the directory where your setup script lives.

If your parent package is located in another directory, use `package_dir = {'parent': 'path/to/your/parent_package'}`.
For huge packages like tensorflow, it is also common to use the helper function [`find_packages`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#packages) to automatically update the packages' list.

Later, when your parent package grows bigger, sub-modules can be split into separated projects. New child project can refer to the parent using `ext_package=['parent']`.

Comment: What if I have several children?

Comment: @BlacKow Simply append them to `ext_modules=[Extension('parent.child1', ...) , Extension('parent.child2', ... ), ...]`.

Answer (score 1):

##### Option1

If you just want to make it a package. Go to `Path\to\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\<package_name>`.
By looking at your source code `package_name` might look like this: `parent-1.0-py3.11-win-amd64.egg`. Rename the `<package_name>` to `parent` and then create a `__init__.py` file there and it's done.

**Results in:**

```
└── site-packages\
    └── parent\
        ├── __init__.py
        └── parent.py
```

**But**, will it do what you want? *I don't think so*

```
#The line below works
from parent.parent import child
child.hello()
#The line below will still not work as parent.parent is a module
from parent.parent.child import hello
```

The second import doesn't work because the `python` file in this `package` is only `parent.py`.

##### Option2

To do `from parent.child import hello` you have to make an individual module `child` which contains function `hello` then follow the package making process explained in `Option 1`.

So your result after compilation looks like this:

```
└── site-packages\
    └── parent\
        ├── __init__.py
        └── child.py
```

##### Option 3

Or if don't want to restructure and want a better way to import, use:

```py
from parent import child
child.hello()
#OR
hello = child.hello
hello()
```

##### Option 4 (Last Option)

> My code is a toy example but I actually want both modules defined on C++ level. I don't want to split them into several modules - since they are sharing some C++ code.

*This is more of a manual way*
**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import Extension, setup
  
# Define the extension module
extension_mod = Extension('main',
                          sources=['custom.cc'])

# Define the setup parameters
setup(name='parent',
      version='1.0',
      description='A C++ extension module for Python.',
      ext_modules=[extension_mod],
      )
```

**Create a structure like this:**

```
└── site-packages\
    └── parent\
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── main.py
        └── child.py
```

****init**.py**

```py
from . import main
```

**child.py**

```py
from . import main
hello = main.child.hello
```

**Now you can do this:**

```
>>> from parent.child import hello
>>> hello()
'Hi, World!'
```

I personally recommend the **`third option`** if there are no strict requirements but if you can't restructure and need the exact structure you may try implementing the last one.

Comment: Check out the last part I added. This is the best I can think of.

Comment: it has multiple files, but they are all compiled into one shared library. Number of c++ files is irrelevant (they can be merged in one file). Their trick was nice because in the end I have one shred library and several top level modules in it

Comment: Why not use **Option 4**? You can just add a few lines to `.py` files, without needing to tweak your `.cc` code

Comment: I can use **Option 4** it still looks like a workaround. I would need to re-import everything on Python level. I was hoping that I was missing some trick that would’ve exposed the submodules hierarchy “stored” in the shared library.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the standard way or not but works the same way you want. *please correct me if it's not correct*.

I deleted the parts related to `parent` in your cpp code and made `child.cpp`. This is the structure of the package dir. For `setup.py` I got the idea from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61956365/building-python-submodules-from-c-extensions-via-cmake)

```
|package
|- parent/
|- - __init__.py
|- - child/
|- - - child.cpp
|- setup.py
```

This is `child.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <Python.h>
#include <string>

std::string hello() {
    return "Hi, World!";
}

static PyObject* hello_world(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
    return PyUnicode_FromString(hello().c_str());
}

static PyMethodDef ChildMethods[] = {
    {"hello", hello_world, METH_NOARGS, ""},
    {nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr}
};

static PyModuleDef ChildModule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "child",
    "A submodule of the parent module.",
    -1,
    ChildMethods,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr

};


PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_child(void) {
    PyObject* child_module = PyModule_Create(&ChildModule);
    if (!child_module) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    return child_module;
}
```

`parent/__init__.py` is:

```py
from .child import *
```

And changed `setup.py` to this:

```py
from setuptools import Extension, setup
  
# Define the extension module
extension_mod = Extension('parent.child',
                          sources=['parent/child/child.cpp'])

# Define the setup parameters
setup(name='parent',
      packages=["parent"],
      version='1.0',
      description='A C++ extension module for Python.',
      ext_modules=[extension_mod],
      )
```

You can also check this [link](https://python.plainenglish.io/building-hybrid-python-c-packages-8985fa1c5b1d)

Comment: It is important to note that setuptools will be deprecated soon. PyBind11 is preferrable

Comment: @Gaston will setuptools be deprecated? or just command line usage of setup.py? I can achieve the same result with `pip install .`

Comment: I'm not sure pybind11 and setuptools do the same thing as each other? And is it not *distutils* that's deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

I'll have to admit that I (unsuccessfully) tried a few things (including adding `packages=["parent"],` in *setup.py* (which is deprecated *BTW*: [[SO]: 'setup.py install is deprecated' warning shows up every time I open a terminal in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73257839/4788546))) before thinking of this:

1. Take the behavior from (referenced) [[Python.Docs]: importlib - Importing a source file directly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly)
2. Replicate it, at least the relevant parts (like adding the module(s) in [[Python.Docs]: sys.modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules) - thanks @DavisHerring for the shorter variant) in *PyInit_parent*

   **Notes**:

   - Although it works, I have a feeling that this is not the most orthodox way, so some might see it as a workaround (*gainarie*) - there is a chance that in some cases it might behave unexpectedly
   - The *@TODO*s are not necessarily required (functionally, it works without them), but I placed them there in order to be "by the book" (and they are part of the things I tried earlier). There's the possibility that some other module constants will be required
   - Functions computing namespace names are designed for a nesting level of 1 (maximum). If you need higher ones (*e.g.* *parent.child.grandchild*) they have to be adapted (maybe to work with strings organized in tree structures), anyway you've got the gist

I modified your code to a working example.

*custom.cc*:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <Python.h>


using std::string;
using std::vector;

typedef vector<string> StrVec;
typedef vector<PyObject*> PPOVec;

static const string dotStr = ".";
static const string parentStr = "parent";
static const string childStr = "child";


static string join(const string &outer, const string &inner, const string &sep = dotStr)
{
    return outer + sep + inner;
}


static StrVec join(const string &outer, const StrVec &inners, const string &sep = dotStr)
{
    StrVec ret;
    for (const string &inner : inners) {
        ret.emplace_back(join(outer, inner, sep));
    }
    return ret;
}


static int tweakModules(const string &pkg, const StrVec &names, const PPOVec &mods)
{
    PyObject *dict = PyImport_GetModuleDict();
    if (!dict) {
        return -1;
    }
    int idx = 0;
    for (StrVec::const_iterator it = names.cbegin(); it != names.cend(); ++it, ++idx) {
        if (PyDict_SetItemString(dict, join(pkg, *it).c_str(), mods[idx])) {
            return -2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


static void decrefMods(const PPOVec &mods)
{
    for (const PyObject *mod : mods) {
        Py_XDECREF(mod);
    }
}


static std::string hello()
{
    return "Hi, World!";
}

static PyObject* py_hello(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    return PyUnicode_FromString(hello().c_str());
}


static PyMethodDef parentMethods[] = {
    {nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr}
};

static PyMethodDef childMethods[] = {
    {"hello", py_hello, METH_NOARGS, ""},
    {nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr}
};


static string childFQ = join(parentStr, childStr);

static PyModuleDef childDef = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    //childStr.c_str(),
    childFQ.c_str(),  // @TODO - cfati: Module FQName (rigorousity's sake)
    "A submodule of the parent module.",
    -1,
    childMethods,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr
};


static PyModuleDef parentDef = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    parentStr.c_str(),
    "A C++ extension module for Python.",
    -1,
    parentMethods,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr
};


PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_parent()
{
    PyObject *parentMod = PyModule_Create(&parentDef);
    if (!parentMod) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    PyObject *childMod = PyModule_Create(&childDef);
    if (!childMod) {
        Py_XDECREF(parentMod);
        return nullptr;
    }

    // @TODO - cfati: Add modules and their names here (to be handled automatically)
    StrVec childrenStrs = {childStr};
    PPOVec mods = {childMod};

    if (tweakModules(parentStr, childrenStrs, mods) < 0) {
        decrefMods(mods);
        Py_XDECREF(parentMod);
        return nullptr;
    }

    int idx = 0;
    for (StrVec::const_iterator it = childrenStrs.cbegin(); it != childrenStrs.cend(); ++it, ++idx) {
        if (PyModule_AddObject(parentMod, it->c_str(), mods[idx]) < 0) {  // @TODO - cfati: Add modules under parent
            decrefMods(mods);
            Py_XDECREF(parentMod);
            return nullptr;
        }
    }

    mods.push_back(parentMod);
    for (PyObject *mod : mods) {
        if (PyModule_AddStringConstant(mod, "__package__", parentStr.c_str()) < 0) {  // @TODO - cfati: Set __package__ for each module
            decrefMods(mods);
            return nullptr;
        }
    }
    return parentMod;
}
```

**Output**:

> ```bash
> (py_pc064_03.10_test0) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q076222409]> ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> custom.cc  setup.py
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> python setup.py build
> running build
> running build_ext
> building 'parent' extension
> creating build
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_pc064_03.10_test0/include -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c custom.cc -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/custom.o
> custom.cc:24:15: warning: ‘StrVec join(const string&, const StrVec&, const string&)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
>    25 | static StrVec join(const string &outer, const StrVec &inners, const string &sep = dotStr)
>       |               ^~~~
> creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
> x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -g -fwrapv -O2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/custom.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/parent.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> build  custom.cc  setup.py
> [064bit prompt]> ls build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/
> parent.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310 python -c "from parent.child import hello;print(hello());print(\"Done.\n\")"
> Hi, World!
> Done.
> ```

References (that might be useful):

- [[Python.Docs]: Extending Python with C or C++](https://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#extending-python-with-c-or-c)
- [[Python.Docs]: Python/C API Reference Manual](https://docs.python.org/c-api/index.html)
- [[Python.Docs]: The import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-import-system)
- [[SO]: How to solve Python-C-API error "This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip."? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75307579/4788546)
- [[SO]: Cpython Extension forcing Memory Leak (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75857942/4788546)